Other meanings of 出目
This is the description of the game Life or Death from Kakegurui volume 1 afterword:

システムしてはルーレットに近いですが、出目が複数あり得ること、出目を当てても利益になるとは限らないところに、おかしみがあります。本来は、安いチップをチマチマ賭けて、出目に一喜一憂するギャンプルなのでしよう。夢子の提案のように100万円チップでやろうものなら、作中のような事態になってしまいます。それにしても、伝統文化研究会のディーラーが美人さんです。

The word 出目 used here seem to have nothing to do with faces appearing on dice. I wonder if this word is synonymous to 結果 (i.e. "outcome" or "result")? If so, 出目を当てる means to successfully guess the outcome, right?

出目 refers to the result of a dice roll, not results in general. If you're asking the difference between 目 and 出目, 目 refers to either 21 pips or 6 faces of a dice. This means サイコロには21の目がある and サイコロには6つの目がある are both understood, but サイコロには21の出目がある and サイコロには6つの出目がある are both incorrect when talking about the physical construction of a dice.

サイコロ

この点は“目”、または“ピップ” (pip)、“スポット” (spot)、まれに“ドット” (dot) とも呼ばれる。日本製の場合、1の面の目は赤く着色されていることが多々ある。
各面に表示される数も“目”と呼ばれ、サイコロを振った結果表示される数を“出目”と呼ぶ。



Thank you but this game does not involve a dice? Ah, it seems like a dice does not necessarily have to be a cube with 6 faces. It can be any object that can uniformly produces numbers.

@JohnDavies 出目 is only used with dice (N-faced polyhedrons used by rolling). If I understand correctly, this game is a mix of 丁半 and roulette, which led to the use of the term 出目.
